# NSwag separate classes for each controller

Tags: c#, nswag, autorest

Coming form the Autorest world, where the Web Client would generate one class per controller, but doesn't seem possible in NSwag using Service Reference within .Net 5

AutoRest generated web clients follow this pattern.
`{BaseWebClient}.{ControllerName}.{Methods}`

For example:
`IWebClient webClient = new WebClient();`
`webClient.Employee.Get()`

In NSwag, it generates all the methods under one class.
`webClient.Employee_get();`

Can somebody confirm if this is the new way or proper way of generating web clients?

Comment: Did you figure this out?